# How to add subfigures in own list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats, subcaption

I want to add subfigure captions (like "61(a)") in my own list of figures.
My code (see example document below) works fine, but as soon as I load the `caption` or `subcaption` package additionally my code results in an empty list.

What I need is that my `\tableoffigures` command has to get along with the following command:

`\usepackage[...,list=true]{subcaption}`

Example document:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{caption} %figure caption
%\usepackage[list=true,lofdepth=2]{subcaption} %subfigure caption
\usepackage{longtable,letltxmacro}

\newcounter{fullfigurecounter}
\newcounter{fulltablecounter}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@starttof[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    % Table format may be changed%%%
    \begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|p{7cm}|}
%       \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \bfseries #2}\tabularnewline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
%       \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline[0.5ex]
        \hline
        \large Table No.  & \large Title of the Table & \large Source \tabularnewline
        \hline
        \endhead % Repeating head
        \@input{\jobname.#1}%  Input the ToF or ToT file 
        \tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
    \setcounter{table}{0}%
    \if@filesw
    \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
    \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\tableoffigures}{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \@starttof{tof}{Abbildungs- und Quellenverzeichnis}
}%

\newcommand{\tableoftables}{%
    \clearpage
    \@starttof{tot}{LIST OF TABLES}%
}%

\def\temp@@a{figure}%
\def\temp@@b{table}%

\LetLtxMacro\captionpkg@caption\caption

\newcommand{\writetofline}[3]{%
    \ifnum\value{fullfigurecounter} > 1
    \tabularnewline
    \protect\hline
    \fi
    \figurename\ #1 & #2 & #3 
}

\newcommand{\writetotline}[3]{%
    \ifnum\value{fulltablecounter} > 1
    \tabularnewline
    \protect\hline
    \fi
    \tablename\ #1 & #2 & #3 
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{somO{Eigene Darstellung}}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
    }{%
        \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
        \stepcounter{fullfigurecounter}%
        \else
        \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
        \stepcounter{fulltablecounter}%
        \fi
        \fi
        \IfValueTF{#2}{%
            \captionpkg@caption[#2]{#3}%
            \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
            \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#2}{#4}}%
            \else
            \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
            \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#2}{#4}}%
            \fi
            \fi
        }{%
            \captionpkg@caption{#3}%
            \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@a
            \addtocontents{tof}{\writetofline{\thefigure}{#3}{#4}}%
            \else%
            \ifx\@currenvir\temp@@b
            \addtocontents{tot}{\writetotline{\thetable}{#3}{#4}}%
            \fi
            \fi
        }%
    }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableoffigures
\clearpage
\tableoftables 
\clearpage

\chapter{A sample for multicol table of contents}
\begin{table}
    \caption[A nice table]{A nice table}[Me!]
\end{table}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Irgendein Bild}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption[Die Sonnenblumen]{Irgendein Bild}[Vincent van Gogh]
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption[List of $ \theta $ signature]{$\theta$ signature}
    \label{theta}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|*{6}{c|}}
        \hline
%       \backslashbox{$ \boldsymbol{\theta} $}{signature}& \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & $ \boldsymbol{\cdots} $ & $ \boldsymbol{t} $\\ \hline
        \textbf{1} & 1 &    2 & 3&  4&  $ \ldots $ &    1+c \\
        \hline
        \textbf{4} &    5 & 6 &     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$ \ldots $} & 7\\ \cline{4-5}
        \hline
        $ \vdots $ &    \multicolumn{6}{c|}{$ \ldots $} \\ \cline{2-6}
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\ifx\subfigure\undefined\else

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
        \caption[flower]{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
        \caption[animal]{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems your redefinition of `\caption` only supports environmants `figure` and `table` but not `subfigure` or `subtable` and also not using `\caption` inside another environment inside a `figure` or `table`. So I would call is: *broken by design*. `\caption` should never depend on `\@currenvir`. Maybe depending on `\@captype` could be used, but not to compare it, but for something like `\csname the\@captype\endcsname`, `\csname fnum@\@captype\endcsname` etc.

Comment: i tried.. but not getting expected output. may i ask you to upload the correct code if possible.

Comment: Sorry, but the shown code is not a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and has to many errors (starting with option *English* instead of *english* to babel) to fix all of them. So you should first reduce it and make it compile without error messages.

Comment: can you help me out with this problem. else refer me some article or site to modify my code. because searching for creating my own list of figures along with subfigure caption to be made. but its complicated. kindly do helpme..

Answer (score 0):

Since `\caption` is subject to re-definition for many environments (`subfigure`, `longtable`, ...), this approach patches the caption package instead, forwarding the burden of dealing with all the different `\caption` implementations to it.

Disadvantages:

1. This solution works only if the caption package is loaded.
2. This solution patches an internal command of the caption package.
3. Since we do not patch `\caption` we need an extra command to specify the source. (I have called it `\source` in my example code below.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[listformat=simple]{caption} %figure caption
\usepackage[list=true,lofdepth=2]{subcaption} %subfigure caption
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@starttof[2]{% (not altered)
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    % Table format may be changed%%%
    \begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{6cm}|p{7cm}|}
%       \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large \bfseries #2}\tabularnewline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline
%       \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\tabularnewline[0.5ex]
        \hline
        \large Table No.  & \large Title of the Table & \large Source \tabularnewline
        \hline
        \endhead % Repeating head
        \@input{\jobname.#1}%  Input the ToF or ToT file 
    \end{longtable}
%   \setcounter{table}{0}% What is this line good for?
    \if@filesw
    \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
    \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\tableoffigures}{% (not altered)
    \cleardoublepage
    \@starttof{tof}{Abbildungs- und Quellenverzeichnis}
}%

\newcommand{\tableoftables}{% (not altered)
    \clearpage
    \@starttof{tot}{LIST OF TABLES}%
}%

\newcommand{\writetofline}[4]{% (one argument added)
    #1~#2 & #3 & #4%
    \tabularnewline
    \protect\hline
}

% New \source{...} command (avoiding patching \caption)
\newcommand*\our@source{}
\newcommand*\source[1]{\renewcommand\our@source{#1}}

% Patch the caption package code which actually writes an entry into the list of figures/tables
% WARNING: We are patching an internal command of the caption package here
\let\caption@@@addcontentsline@ORI\caption@@@addcontentsline
\renewcommand*\caption@@@addcontentsline[4]{%
  % #1 = "lof" / "lot"
  % #2 = "figure" / "table" / "subfigure" / "subtable"
  % #3 = caption list number (content could be altered using option "listformat=...")
  % #4 = caption list entry (as given in \caption)
  % \@captype = "figure" / "table"
  %
  % Make entry in regular List of Figures/Tables (this could be dropped if no regular lof/lot is desired)
  \caption@@@addcontentsline@ORI{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  % lof -> tof / lot -> tot
  \edef\our@ext{#1}\edef\our@ext{t\expandafter\@gobble\our@ext}%
  % Set default source, if none was set by the user
  \ifx\our@source\@empty
      \def\our@source{Eigene Darstellung}%
  \fi
  % Add contents line to tof/tot
  \addtocontents{\our@ext}{\writetofline{\@nameuse{\@captype name}}{#3}{#4}{\our@source}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableoffigures
\clearpage
\tableoftables 
\clearpage

\chapter{A sample for multicol table of contents}
\begin{table}
    \source{Me!}
    \caption[A nice table]{A nice table}
\end{table}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Irgendein Bild}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \source{Vincent van Gogh}
    \caption[Die Sonnenblumen]{Irgendein Bild}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption[List of $ \theta $ signature]{$\theta$ signature}
    \label{theta}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|*{6}{c|}}
        \hline
%       \backslashbox{$ \boldsymbol{\theta} $}{signature}& \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & $ \boldsymbol{\cdots} $ & $ \boldsymbol{t} $\\ \hline
        \textbf{1} & 1 &    2 & 3&  4&  $ \ldots $ &    1+c \\
        \hline
        \textbf{4} &    5 & 6 &     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$ \ldots $} & 7\\ \cline{4-5}
        \hline
        $ \vdots $ &    \multicolumn{6}{c|}{$ \ldots $} \\ \cline{2-6}
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\ifx\subfigure\undefined\else

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
        \caption[flower]{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
        \caption[animal]{}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much and you save my day. but one problem occurs while compiling, that what i used is xelatex compiler. but it doesn't support xelatex. where it supports only pdftex and luatex. what is the reason behind and what can be done for that? thank you in advance.

Comment: I can compile the document above without problems using xelatex as well (MikTeX, up-to-date). What error message do you get?

Comment: Drivers other than  `pdftex' and `luatex'  are not supported.